# How does one pluralize a name that ends with a silent x?

Tags: grammatical-number, proper-nouns

My friend Paul Robichaux (noted [O'Reilly author](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925458.do), [Exchange MVP](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/spotlight/user/9179), and [all-around good guy](http://paulrobichaux.com/)) was tagged in a Facebook post today in which the poster lamented that they “were missing a few tall Robichauxs.”

A plural that reflects pronunciation looks sensible and certainly less awkward than `Robichauxes`. Is it correct in this case?

Comment: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-make-family-names-plural

Comment: Big difference between spelling and sound.  Add an **s** but still leave the **x** silent.  So, the De Fauxs would still be pronounced like the Defoes.

Comment: [In 1911, two years after **Dave J. Robichaux's** birth, his parents moved back to their native Lafourche Parish, where **the Robichaux's and Folses** have lived since the early period of settlement.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22where+the+Robichaux%27s%22)

Comment: Per [The Chicago Manual of Style Online](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Plurals.html): An apostrophe is never used to form the plural of family names. Write “the Wallaces,” “the Joneses,” the “Jordans,” etc. See paragraph 7.8 of the sixteenth edition of CMOS for the full statement of the applicable rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robichaux is already pluralised from its original French. I would treat it as *plurale tantum* (plural only) in recognition of its roots and so I would render it as "they were missing a few tall Robichaux".

Comment: Generally, we don't follow pluralization rules of other languages when we pluralize a loanword or proper name in English.

Comment: I agree with Steven. I would pluralize it based on the spelling, which would be Robichauxes. (And I am not sure why the OP considers that awkward.)

Comment: Like in this article about a couple with the last name Robichaux: http://blog.al.com/wire/2011/12/mississippi_supreme_court_over.html

Comment: @StevenLittman Undoubtedly based on the 19th-century idea that, since English is the likely language of the Almighty, why bother making gestures to the lesser tongues!

Comment: @WS2--I'm sure you're being facetious, but the real reason is that foreign tongues have so many different ways to pluralize, English speakers could not, or would not, be able to keep them straight (much less even be aware of which language which word came from).  I believe that other languages have similar patterns.

Comment: @StevenLittman I always try to use plurals like *referenda*, *croci*, *hippopotami* etc. But try them on a site like this and you will get howled down. There is still an attitude of treating foreign words as though they were infectious diseases - best avoided.

Comment: @StevenLittman Plateaux and Châteaux are both accepted plural forms in English.

Comment: @efran--As are plateaus and chateaus.  Plateaus more, at least in the US, because the word has been fully Anglicized.  See http://grammarist.com/spelling/plateaus-plateaux/ for a complete discussion.  Chateaus has not become the prevalent form, because, you know, castles.